# python - pandas, how to reduce the row dataframe that has same value?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

first of all, I have one data frame that merged from two data frames

to be clear,

```
  df_dog          df_cat
dog1  numid     cat1 numid
abc   n11       122  n11
abc   n21       123  n21
abc   n31       123  n31
abd   n41       121  n41
abd   n41       121  n31
```

i have converted the data into a vector by

```
df_com = df_dog.merge(df_cat, on='numid', how='inner').set_index(['dog1','cat1'])

pd.get_dummies(df_com.numid).sort_index(level=0)
```

and the result shows as

```
          n11 n21 n31 n41 
dog1 cat1
abc  122   1   0   0   0
abc  123   0   1   0   0
abc  123   0   0   1   0
abc  121   0   0   0   1
abc  121   0   0   1   0
```

considered on

```
    abc  123   0   1   0   0
    abc  123   0   0   1   0
    abc  121   0   0   0   1
    abc  121   0   0   1   0
```

there is duplicated row which are 'abc 123' and 'abc 121'

so, i would like to reduce this duplicated data but still would like to remain the both of values, to be obvious, i would like to see the result as

```
          n11 n21 n31 n41 
dog1 cat1
abc  122   1   0   0   0
abc  123   0   1   1   0
abc  121   0   0   1   1
```

i have tried 'group by' but the results are very weird :(

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) by both levels:

```
pd.get_dummies(df_com.numid).sort_index(level=0).max(level=[0,1])

print (df)
           n11  n21  n31  n41
dog1 cat1                    
abc  122     1    0    0    0
     123     0    1    1    0
     121     0    0    1    1
```

Answer with input data:

```
df_com = df_dog.merge(df_cat, on='numid').set_index(['dog1','cat1'])
print (df_com)
          numid
dog1 cat1      
abc  122    n11
     123    n21
     123    n31
     121    n31
abd  121    n41
     121    n41

print (pd.get_dummies(df_com.numid).sort_index(level=0))
           n11  n21  n31  n41
dog1 cat1                    
abc  121     0    0    1    0
     122     1    0    0    0
     123     0    1    0    0
     123     0    0    1    0
abd  121     0    0    0    1
     121     0    0    0    1

df = pd.get_dummies(df_com.numid).sort_index(level=0).max(level=[0,1])
print (df)
           n11  n21  n31  n41
dog1 cat1                    
abc  121     0    0    1    0
     122     1    0    0    0
     123     0    1    1    0
abd  121     0    0    0    1
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but it seems like some data is missed. maybe it wrongs since this line -> df_com = df_dog.merge(df_cat, on='numid', how='inner').set_index(['dog1','cat1'])

Comment: @Sungjin - I try your input data and get different output. So what is expected output from `df_dog.merge(df_cat, on='numid').set_index(['dog1','cat1'])` ?

Comment: the expected output from that one is I would like to combine/merge 2 data frames (dog and cat) using the numid